# How to set a foreign key for a table in C#?

Tags: c#, sql, database, foreign-keys, constraints

I am working on a program that creates a database and builds the dimension and fact tables. I am having trouble setting the foreign keys and the constraint.

Here is the actual SQL for what I am trying to do:

```
 CREATE TABLE FactSalesOrders
  (ProductKey int NOT NULL REFERENCES DimProduct(ProductKey),
   CustomerKey int NOT NULL REFERENCES DimCustomer(CustomerKey),
   SalespersonKey int NOT NULL REFERENCES DimSalesperson(SalepersonKey),
   OrderDateKey int NOT NULL REFERENCES DimDate(DateKey),
   OrderNo int NOT NULL,
   ItemNo int Not NULL,
   Quantity int Not NULL,
   SalesAmount money NOT NULL,
   Cost money NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT [PK_FactSalesOrders] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED
    (
        [ProductKey],[CustomerKey],[SalespersonKey],[OrderDateKey],[OrderNo],[ItemNo]
    )
  )
```

Here is the fact table:

```
    //Creating Fact Table
    Table factTable = new Table(myDatabase, "Fact Table");

        //Column One: Product Key
        Column ProductKey = new Column(factTable, "ProductKey", DataType.Int);
        ProductKey.Nullable = false;
        factTable.Columns.Add(ProductKey);

        //Column Two: Customer Key 
        Column CustomerKey = new Column(factTable, "CustomerKey", DataType.Int);
        CustomerKey.Nullable = false;
        factTable.Columns.Add(CustomerKey);

        //Column Three: Sales Person Key
        Column SalespersonKey = new Column(factTable, "SalespersonKey", DataType.Int);
        SalespersonKey.Nullable = false;
        factTable.Columns.Add(SalespersonKey);

        //Column Four: Order Date Key
        Column OrderDateKey = new Column(factTable, "OrderDateKey", DataType.Int);
        OrderDateKey.Nullable = false;
        factTable.Columns.Add(OrderDateKey);

        //Column Five: Order Number
        Column OrderNo = new Column(factTable, "OrderNo", DataType.Int);
        OrderNo.Nullable = false;
        factTable.Columns.Add(OrderNo);

        //Column Six: Item Number
        Column ItemNo = new Column(factTable, "ItemNo", DataType.Int);
        ItemNo.Nullable = false;
        factTable.Columns.Add(ItemNo);

        //Column Seven: Quantity
        Column Quantity = new Column(factTable, "Quantity", DataType.Int);
        Quantity.Nullable = false;
        factTable.Columns.Add(Quantity);

        //Column Eight: Sales Amount
        Column SalesAmount = new Column(factTable, "SalesAmount", DataType.Money);
        SalesAmount.Nullable = false;
        factTable.Columns.Add(SalesAmount);

        //Column Nine: Cost
        Column Cost = new Column(factTable, "Cost", DataType.Money);
        Cost.Nullable = false;
        factTable.Columns.Add(Cost);

    factTable.Create();
```

Here is all of the C# code (NOTE: The fact table is at the bottom) :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;

namespace Hillstar_Project
{



    class Program
    {



        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Server myServer = new Server(@"localhost");
            Boolean exit = false;
            while (exit == false)
            {
                Console.Write("Enter Name Of Data Warehouse: ");
                String NewDatabaseName = Console.ReadLine();

                SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("user id=app;" +
                                           "password=test;server=localhost;" +
                                           "Trusted_Connection=yes;" +
                                           "database=test; " +
                                           "connection timeout=30");

                try
                {
                    myConnection.Open();
                    Console.WriteLine("Successful Connection");
                    try
                    {
                        //DatabaseObjectCreation(myServer);

                        DataWarehouseCreation(myServer, NewDatabaseName);
                        Console.ReadLine();
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
                    }

                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
                }

                Console.Write("Exit? (y/n): ");
                if (Console.ReadLine() == "y")
                {
                    exit = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    exit = false;
                }
            }


        }





        private static void DataWarehouseCreation(Server myServer, String NewDatabaseName)
        {
            //Drop the database if it exists
            if (myServer.Databases[NewDatabaseName] != null){
                Console.Write("Are you sure you want to override existing database? (y/n): ");
                if(Console.ReadLine() == "y"){
                    myServer.Databases[NewDatabaseName].Drop();
                }
                else{
                    Console.WriteLine("Database was not overwritten...");
                    return;
                }
                }


            //Create database
            Database myDatabase = new Database(myServer, NewDatabaseName);
            myDatabase.Create();




            //Creating DimProduct
            Table DimProduct = new Table(myDatabase, "DimProduct");

                //Column One: Product Key
                Column productKey = new Column(DimProduct, "ProductKey", DataType.Int);
                productKey.Nullable = false;
                DimProduct.Columns.Add(productKey);

                //Column Two: Product Alt Key
                Column productAltKey = new Column(DimProduct, "ProductAltKey", DataType.NVarChar(10));
                productAltKey.Nullable = false;
                DimProduct.Columns.Add(productAltKey);

                //Column Three: Product Name
                Column productName = new Column(DimProduct, "ProductName", DataType.NVarChar(50));
                productName.Nullable = true;
                DimProduct.Columns.Add(productName);

                //Column Four: Product Description
                Column productDescription = new Column(DimProduct, "ProductDescription", DataType.NVarChar(100));
                productDescription.Nullable = true;
                DimProduct.Columns.Add(productDescription);

                //Column Five: Product Catagory Name
                Column productCatagoryName = new Column(DimProduct, "ProductCatagoryName", DataType.NVarChar(50));
                productCatagoryName.Nullable = true;
                DimProduct.Columns.Add(productCatagoryName);

                //Primary Key
                Index primaryKeyIndex1 = new Index(DimProduct, "PK_DimProduct");
                primaryKeyIndex1.IndexKeyType = IndexKeyType.DriPrimaryKey;
                primaryKeyIndex1.IndexedColumns.Add(new IndexedColumn(primaryKeyIndex1, "productKey"));
                DimProduct.Indexes.Add(primaryKeyIndex1);

            DimProduct.Create();
            Console.WriteLine("DimProduct Table Created");


            //Creating DimCustomer
            Table DimCustomer = new Table(myDatabase, "DimCustomer");

                //Column One: Customer Key
                Column customerKey = new Column(DimCustomer, "CustomerKey", DataType.Int);
                productKey.Nullable = false;
                DimCustomer.Columns.Add(customerKey);

                //Column Two: Customer Alt Key
                Column customerAltKey = new Column(DimCustomer, "CustomerAltKey", DataType.NVarChar(10));
                productAltKey.Nullable = false;
                DimCustomer.Columns.Add(customerAltKey);

                //Column Three: Customer Name
                Column customerName = new Column(DimCustomer, "CustomerName", DataType.NVarChar(50));
                customerName.Nullable = true;
                DimCustomer.Columns.Add(customerName);

                //Column Four: Customer Email
                Column customerEmail = new Column(DimCustomer, "CustomerEmail", DataType.NVarChar(50));
                customerEmail.Nullable = true;
                DimCustomer.Columns.Add(customerEmail);

                //Column Five: Customer Geography Key
                Column customerGeographyKey = new Column(DimCustomer, "CustomerGeographyKey", DataType.Int);
                customerGeographyKey.Nullable = true;
                DimCustomer.Columns.Add(customerGeographyKey);

                //Primary Key
                Index primaryKeyIndex2 = new Index(DimCustomer, "PK_DimCustomer");
                primaryKeyIndex2.IndexKeyType = IndexKeyType.DriPrimaryKey;
                primaryKeyIndex2.IndexedColumns.Add(new IndexedColumn(primaryKeyIndex2, "customerKey"));
                DimCustomer.Indexes.Add(primaryKeyIndex2);

            DimCustomer.Create();
            Console.WriteLine("DimCustomer Table Created");

            //Creating DimSalesPerson
            Table DimSalesperson = new Table(myDatabase, "DimSalesperson");

                //Column One: Salesperson Key
                Column salespersonKey = new Column(DimSalesperson, "SalespersonKey", DataType.Int);
                salespersonKey.Nullable = false;
                DimSalesperson.Columns.Add(salespersonKey);

                //Column Two: Salesperson Alt Key
                Column salespersonAltKey = new Column(DimSalesperson, "SalespersonAltKey", DataType.NVarChar(10));
                salespersonAltKey.Nullable = false;
                DimSalesperson.Columns.Add(salespersonAltKey);

                //Column Three: Salesperson Name
                Column salespersonName = new Column(DimSalesperson, "SalespersonName", DataType.NVarChar(50));
                salespersonName.Nullable = true;
                DimSalesperson.Columns.Add(salespersonName);

                //Column Four: Store Name
                Column storeName = new Column(DimSalesperson, "StoreName", DataType.NVarChar(50));
                storeName.Nullable = true;
                DimSalesperson.Columns.Add(storeName);

                //Column Five: Store Geography Key
                Column storeGeographyKey = new Column(DimSalesperson, "StoreGeographyKey", DataType.Int);
                storeGeographyKey.Nullable = true;
                DimSalesperson.Columns.Add(storeGeographyKey);

                //Primary Key
                Index primaryKeyIndex3 = new Index(DimSalesperson, "PK_DimSalesperson");
                primaryKeyIndex3.IndexKeyType = IndexKeyType.DriPrimaryKey;
                primaryKeyIndex3.IndexedColumns.Add(new IndexedColumn(primaryKeyIndex3, "salespersonKey"));
                DimSalesperson.Indexes.Add(primaryKeyIndex3);

            DimSalesperson.Create();
            Console.WriteLine("DimSalesperson Table Created");

            //Creating DimDate
            Table DimDate = new Table(myDatabase, "DimDate");

                //Column One: Date Key
                Column dateKey = new Column(DimDate, "DateKey", DataType.Int);
                dateKey.Nullable = false;
                DimDate.Columns.Add(dateKey);

                //Column Two: Calendar Year
                Column calendarYear = new Column(DimDate, "CalendarYear", DataType.Int);
                calendarYear.Nullable = false;
                DimDate.Columns.Add(calendarYear);

                //Column Three: Calendar Quarter 
                Column calendarQuarter = new Column(DimDate, "Calendar Quarter", DataType.Int);
                calendarQuarter.Nullable = false;
                DimDate.Columns.Add(calendarQuarter);

                //Column Four: Month Of Year
                Column monthOfYear = new Column(DimDate, "MonthOfYear", DataType.Int);
                monthOfYear.Nullable = false;
                DimDate.Columns.Add(monthOfYear);

                //Column Five: Month Name
                Column monthName = new Column(DimDate, "MonthName", DataType.NVarChar(15));
                monthName.Nullable = false;
                DimDate.Columns.Add(monthName);

                //Column Six: Day Of Month
                Column dayOfMonth = new Column(DimDate, "DayOfMonth", DataType.Int);
                dayOfMonth.Nullable = false;
                DimDate.Columns.Add(dayOfMonth);

                //Column Seven: Day Of Week
                Column dayOfWeek = new Column(DimDate, "DayOfWeek", DataType.Int);
                dayOfWeek.Nullable = false;
                DimDate.Columns.Add(dayOfWeek);

                //Column Eight: Day Name
                Column dayName = new Column(DimDate, "DayName", DataType.NVarChar(15));
                dayName.Nullable = false;
                DimDate.Columns.Add(dayName);

                //Column Nine: Fiscal Year
                Column fiscalYear = new Column(DimDate, "FiscalYear", DataType.Int);
                fiscalYear.Nullable = false;
                DimDate.Columns.Add(fiscalYear);

                //Column Ten: Fiscal Quarter
                Column fiscalQuarter = new Column(DimDate, "FiscalQuarter", DataType.Int);
                fiscalQuarter.Nullable = false;
                DimDate.Columns.Add(fiscalQuarter);

                //Primary Key
                Index primaryKeyIndex4 = new Index(DimDate, "PK_DimDate");
                primaryKeyIndex4.IndexKeyType = IndexKeyType.DriPrimaryKey;
                primaryKeyIndex4.IndexedColumns.Add(new IndexedColumn(primaryKeyIndex4, "dateKey"));
                DimDate.Indexes.Add(primaryKeyIndex4);


            DimDate.Create();
            Console.WriteLine("DimDate Table Created");



            //Creating Fact Table
            Table factTable = new Table(myDatabase, "Fact Table");

            //Column One: Product Key
            Column ProductKey = new Column(factTable, "ProductKey", DataType.Int);
            ProductKey.Nullable = false;
            factTable.Columns.Add(ProductKey);

            //Column Two: Customer Key 
            Column CustomerKey = new Column(factTable, "CustomerKey", DataType.Int);
            CustomerKey.Nullable = false;
            factTable.Columns.Add(CustomerKey);

            //Column Three: Sales Person Key
            Column SalespersonKey = new Column(factTable, "SalespersonKey", DataType.Int);
            SalespersonKey.Nullable = false;
            factTable.Columns.Add(SalespersonKey);

            //Column Four: Order Date Key
            Column OrderDateKey = new Column(factTable, "OrderDateKey", DataType.Int);
            OrderDateKey.Nullable = false;
            factTable.Columns.Add(OrderDateKey);

            //Column Five: Order Number
            Column OrderNo = new Column(factTable, "OrderNo", DataType.Int);
            OrderNo.Nullable = false;
            factTable.Columns.Add(OrderNo);

            //Column Six: Item Number
            Column ItemNo = new Column(factTable, "ItemNo", DataType.Int);
            ItemNo.Nullable = false;
            factTable.Columns.Add(ItemNo);

            //Column Seven: Quantity
            Column Quantity = new Column(factTable, "Quantity", DataType.Int);
            Quantity.Nullable = false;
            factTable.Columns.Add(Quantity);

            //Column Eight: Sales Amount
            Column SalesAmount = new Column(factTable, "SalesAmount", DataType.Money);
            SalesAmount.Nullable = false;
            factTable.Columns.Add(SalesAmount);

            //Column Nine: Cost
            Column Cost = new Column(factTable, "Cost", DataType.Money);
            Cost.Nullable = false;
            factTable.Columns.Add(Cost);

            factTable.Create();
            Console.WriteLine("Fact Table Created");


            Console.WriteLine("Database Created");


        }   

    }
}
```

Comment: Please remove any unnecessary code so that we can easily see your issue and help you solve your problem.

Comment: I added the specific part of the code I need help with. Thank you.

Comment: Is this a school project? If not, why not use EF6 or 7 or some other ORM? If it's homework, I wish you that this part will be over soon.

Comment: It is for my internship. This is just a small project that they gave me. I guess they are just trying to see how resourceful I can be.

Answer (score 3):

Create the foreign key constraint and add to the child table

```
 ForeignKeyConstraint fk = new ForeignKeyConstraint(
        "ForeignKey", objCustomer.Columns["CustomerID"], objOrder.Columns["CustomerID"]);
    objOrder.Constraints.Add(fk);
```

You can use following links for your references.
[Refer Link1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/st1t2c35(v=vs.110).aspx)
[Refer Link2](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Blogs/5656/creating-a-foreign-key-constraint.aspx)

Comment: I found those articles last night and tried them, but I cannot get the ForeignKeyConstraint class to work with my code. According to the msdn documentation, It has four parameters with the first one being a dataset. I am unsure what I need to be passing into this parameter. Thank you.